# how to get custom fields value in techtalk jira rest client

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

I trying to get the custom fields value using this line of code

```
var issue2 = client.SearchIssues("project='CG Portal' AND issue = 'CP-166' AND Published is not EMPTY")
```

but there's no option for custom fields value.

any suggestion on how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this syntax: `customfield_XXX` where XXX is the id of the custom field.

I.e.:

```
customfield_1234='4321'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what i wanted was to get the value of the custom field sorry for my question. i just edited it. thanks

Comment: You get that answer in the comment section here: https://github.com/techtalk/JiraRestClient/commit/3ebff9b5ae6d829b0d68ad3b7bfcb6eeb1c045ab